# Bypassing auto mount at boot time

Tags: fstab, automounting

I have set several folders to mount at startup into fstab.  This works fine.

However, I would like to be able to bypass the mounting process in some occasions.
Typically, when I know the remote folders are not available.

Is there a mean to bypass the auto mounting process at boot time?

I thank you for your help.

Comment: Usually you can add the mounting option “nofail” to do exactly that.  It will try to mount, but if the partition or share is not available, it will simply skip mounting it.  If this is what you are looking for, I can convert this comment to an answer.

Comment: Perfect. I added a proper answer for you as well now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to make a partition or network share optional, you can define the mount option `nofail` comma-separated to the other options you have defined.

What will happen is, the system will still attempt to mount the partition/share, but if it is not available or not accessible for whatever reason, it will silently fail and continue to boot the system.

The fstab entry would look something like this:

```
/dev/sdc2   /mnt/your_partition   ext4   defaults,nofail   1   2
```